# Get Request Headers after the request has been made

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am making a POST call to an api that modifies the Request Headers/Request Cookies before it returns a response. Inside the Request Headers/Cookies it inserts a Cookie value that I need in order to maintain a session.

So basically I need to access the modified Request Header after I get back a response from the api.

I'm using Angular $http and tried setting up an interceptor but still can't seem to figure it out. All I get back is the original request headers.

Unfortunately I don't have access to modify the api to return any of this info in the Response instead of the returning it in the Request.

Comment: Can you show what you want using postman

Comment: So why can't you just read the cookie?

Comment: So turns out the reason I couldn't see it in the response header, and the reason I couldn't access the cookie was because the cookies were httpOnly.